# Sudoku Recursion, accepting zeros as legal

Tags: c++, for-loop, recursion, vector, bounds

I am building a recursive Sudoku solver but I have run into an issue. It seems that my legality function is accepting 0's in the final answer. It is not assigning zeros however, zeros are used as a place holder to mark an unfilled value. When I run the program, I get output like this...

```
**************************************************
 7  4  3 | 8  2  1 | 0  0  0 
 0  6  8 | 0  9  0 | 0  1  0 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  6 | 0  0  4 
---------|---------|---------
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 2  3  9 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 4  1  5 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
---------|---------|---------
 9  0  0 | 5  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 0  2  0 | 0  1  0 | 7  4  0 
 0  0  0 | 2  0  0 | 9  0  5 
**************************************************
**************************************************
 7  4  3 | 8  2  1 | 5  0  0 
 0  6  8 | 0  9  0 | 0  1  0 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  6 | 0  0  4 
---------|---------|---------
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 2  3  9 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 4  1  5 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
---------|---------|---------
 9  0  0 | 5  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 0  2  0 | 0  1  0 | 7  4  0 
 0  0  0 | 2  0  0 | 9  0  5 
**************************************************
**************************************************
 7  4  3 | 8  2  1 | 5  6  0 
 0  6  8 | 0  9  0 | 0  1  0 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  6 | 0  0  4 
---------|---------|---------
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 2  3  9 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 4  1  5 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
---------|---------|---------
 9  0  0 | 5  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 0  2  0 | 0  1  0 | 7  4  0 
 0  0  0 | 2  0  0 | 9  0  5 
**************************************************
**************************************************
 7  4  3 | 8  2  1 | 5  6  0 
 2  6  8 | 0  9  0 | 0  1  0 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  6 | 0  0  4 
---------|---------|---------
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 2  3  9 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 4  1  5 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
---------|---------|---------
 9  0  0 | 5  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 0  2  0 | 0  1  0 | 7  4  0 
 0  0  0 | 2  0  0 | 9  0  5 
**************************************************
```

As you can see by these printouts of the puzzle as it's being solved, it accepts a zero as the last number in the first column. I can't find anywhere in my code where it would allow that to happen. Also, I noticed when I was compiling that sometimes I would think I would run into memory that I was supposed to be in, but it allows me to go. I feel like my functions sometimes take things out of thin air.

Here are my legality functions:

```
bool Board::isRowLegal(int row){
    bool present[9] = {};
    for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.size(); ++i){
        if(theBoard[row][i] != 0){
            if(present[(theBoard[row][i]) - 1]){
                return false;
            }
            present[(theBoard[row][i]) - 1] = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Board::isColumnLegal(int column){
    bool present[9] = {};
    for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.size(); ++i){
        if(theBoard[i][column] != 0){
            if(present[(theBoard[i][column]) - 1]){
                return false;
            }
            present[(theBoard[i][column]) - 1] = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Board::isPanelLegal(int rowStart, int colStart){
    // Store the numbers in the panel in one vector.
    vector<int> currentPanel;
    for(int i = rowStart; i < rowStart + THREE; ++i){
        cout << endl;
        for(int j = colStart; j < colStart + THREE; ++j){
            cout << theBoard[i][j];
            currentPanel.push_back(theBoard[i][j]);
        }  
    }

    bool present[9] = {};
    cout << endl << currentPanel.size() << endl;
    for(int k = 0; k < currentPanel.size(); ++k){
        if(currentPanel[k] != 0){
            if(present[currentPanel[k] - 1]){
                return false;
            }
            present[currentPanel[k] - 1] = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I know it is confusing with the subscripts, but as a general rule, I start at subscript one in order to find the numbers. So the 7 in the first row, first column is coordinate 1, 1. Not 0, 0.

I believe it is a bound issue, maybe I am not checking all the numbers in one instance, however my young programming eyes aren't seeing it.

Also could someone explain why in the isPanelLegal I have to put present[currentPanel[k] - 1]. I can see why in the others because the vector starts at 1, but in isPanelLegal, the vector starts at zero since I just created it in the first part of the function. It works with the -1 and does not work without it.

Recursion part...

```
    if(board.isBoardFull()){
        cout << "here" << endl;
        board.display(outStream);
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = ONE; i <= NINE; ++i){
        for(int j = ONE; j <= NINE; ++j){
            //cout << "original" << board.getSquare(i, j) << "coord: " << i << ", " << j << endl;
            if(board.getSquare(i, j) == ZERO){
                //cout << "original: " << board.getSquare(i, j) << "coord: " << i << ", " << j << endl;
                for(int k = ONE; k <= NINE; ++k){
                    board.setSquare(i, j, k);
                    if(board.isLegal(1, 10, 1, 10)){
                        board.display(outStream);
                        addSquare(depth, outStream);
                                            return true;
                    }
                    board.unsetSquare(i, j);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    board.display(outStream);
    return false;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is it a general rule for you to start at subscript 1? Is it just that it makes more sense in your head or there is an actual reason for it in your code? I don't fully follow. If it's the makes-sense one, maybe try going the other way, else it will bite you in the butt later in your programming career, either with a group project or at a job.

Comment: I know, but I am starting at one in order to better visualize the grid. Do you see any inconsistencies with the 0 and 1 thing, maybe that is where the problem is?

Comment: I realize it is a bad habit, I do not doing it normal programming, just when visualizing a table or grid like this one.

Comment: You could always output a space before delving into outputting the grid. The extra space in memory you're not using for the first column could get confusing, and you will need to be extra careful. It's best to just go with 0-indexed arrays. I will look through your code and see if it has any inconsistencies due to this, but either way, it's generally not a good idea to just leave the first value of an array uninitialized/with junk data that just takes up memory.

Comment: Believe me, I know, our code has to work with our professors display functions, and he indexes his tables at one, so I must make it correspond.

Comment: Of course your functions accept zero as legal, what with all these `if (... != 0)`.

Comment: Put this in a debugger, and step through your code, watching the values of variables.  The answer will be obvious then.

Comment: @abelenky what is the best way to do that? I just updated to OS X Mavericks, and gdb is no longer included on the command line, I have  been using lldb, but I do not know how to step through lines. Can you point me in the direction of a good tutorial?

Comment: You need to loop from 1 to array size + 1 : `for (i = 1; i < size()+1; ++i)` or change the inequality - `<` to `<=`. Otherwise you're always missing the last element of the array.

Comment: The size of the array is 10, There is a blank 0 at the 0 index. Then the numbers are added so at [1][1] there is a 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is here:

```
bool Board::isRowLegal(int row){
    bool present[9] = {};
    for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.size(); ++i){
        if(theBoard[row][i] != 0){ // This line
            if(present[(theBoard[row][i]) - 1]){
                return false;
            }
            present[(theBoard[row][i]) - 1] = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In your for loop if every number is 0 the function will return true. What you need to do is return false if you find a 0 (assuming 0 is never legal, which I think is the case with sudoku).

```
bool Board::isRowLegal(int row){
    bool present[9] = {};
    for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.size(); ++i){
        if(theBoard[row][i] == 0)
            return false;

        if(present[(theBoard[row][i]) - 1])
            return false;

        present[(theBoard[row][i]) - 1] = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Same for the column.

Edit: Oh I just realized you may also need to do i <= theBoard.size() in your for loops. If you're trying to go from 1-9 and the board size is 9, going < will take you from 1-8. This is another reason why you should start from 0 as the other people said. Things just get confusing if you start an array at 1 without a proper reason.

Comment: That makes sense. I will try it first thing in the morning. Getting late on the east coast. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TrevorHutto is 0 being used to signify an unpopulated value? If so, and if `isRowLegal` is to check the incremental current legal state (no values that *are* present are repeated unless it is the unoccupied-sentinal), then this is wrong. A legal "state" must satisfy the condition that no occupied cell value is duplicated in a row, column or panel, and the key word there is *occupied*.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's true. I wasn't exactly sure what the zeroes are supposed to represent. Either way though if the row contains a 0 it shouldn't be a legal row, so it should return false. I'm not sure if this is the final issue, but it will prevent rows with 0s claiming to be legal.

Comment: We can disagree on the legal row state, as it is ultimately purpose-driven by the caller. If a row is partially occupied it is still *legal* so long as none of the occupied values are duplicated in that row. Participatory column validation opens another issue, but ironically the two of them *combined* eliminate the panel-level check (gotta wrap your head around that to see it =). Were the name of this function `isLegalCompleteRow` I would whole-heartedly agree with your assessment, btw.

Comment: Yes, @WhozCraig that is right, the zeros are used to represent unpopulated values, I should rephrase my question to include that. So the problem is that it is not filling some zeros, while others it is filling. I cannot find the spot in my code where that could happen.

Comment: @EricBarr just saw your edit, about the plus equal to, I don't think that is right because the size is ten, there is a zero at index 0 to offset the vector that way the coordinates start at 1. So the vector has 10 elements in it. One zero, then the 9 cells in that row.

Comment: You might need something like WhozCraig suggested with a "isLegalCompleteRow" that you call before exiting. The way the checks are set up right now (in your code, not mine) allows 0s and nothing you've shown requires the row to be full. As far as we can see a board of all 0s would be considered a valid stopping point for your program.

Comment: I don't really see the need for that, I just posted the recursion part, it goes through all the squares, and adds squares then tests to see if the board is legal. If not, it takes that square away and tries the next value. It should fill everything until a function called `isBoardFull` returns true.